# Message log css scroll to bottom

Tags: html, css

I have just introduced a message log in my app.

I have set a max height on the div containing the log and would like it to automatically scroll to the bottom of the log.

Is there a way to achieve this using on CSS. I could solve it with a little bit of of Javascript but if possible I would like to avoid that.

Code:

Css

```
.message-board {
  max-height: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Html

```
<div class="well message-board">
  <div class="message">
    <strong>UserName</strong><em>2015-08-21</em>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
  ...
  <div class="message">
    <strong>UserName</strong><em>2015-08-21</em>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible with a HTML/CSS only solution :(

Comment: You might want to opt to invert the log, so that new entries are added at the top.

Comment: I went with the inverting of the log for now. And changed the general styling to be more like comments instead of a chat kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Just with pure CSS it is **not possible**. You can do it with JavaScript though:

```
setInterval(function() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('message-log');
  elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
}, 1000);
```

The above code happens every second.

**Snippet / Demo**

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('message-log');
  elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
}, 1000);
```

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI'; margin: 0 0 10px; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
#message-log {max-height: 100px; width: 200px; overflow: auto;}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('message-log').innerHTML += '<p>Pages you view in incognito tabs won’t stick around in your browser’s history, cookie store, or search history after you’ve closed all of your incognito tabs. Any files you download or bookmarks you create will be kept. Learn more about incognito browsing Going incognito doesn’t hide your browsing from your employer, your internet service provider, or the websites you visit.</p>'; return false;">Add message.</a>
<div id="message-log"></div>
```

**Partial Pure CSS Hack**

Or another possible solution is to prepend, instead of append. See below:

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI'; margin: 0 0 10px; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
#message-log {max-height: 100px; width: 200px; overflow: auto;}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('message-log').innerHTML = '<p>New messages come here. Pages you view in incognito tabs won’t stick around in your browser’s history, cookie store, or search history after you’ve closed all of your incognito tabs. Any files you download or bookmarks you create will be kept. Learn more about incognito browsing Going incognito doesn’t hide your browsing from your employer, your internet service provider, or the websites you visit.</p>' + document.getElementById('message-log').innerHTML; return false;">Add message.</a>
<div id="message-log"></div>
```

Comment: Op wanted a css solution.

Comment: @n01ze CSS not possible.

Comment: @n01ze Updated the answer with a CSS solution too! `:P`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I decided to go in a different direction but your input might be used at another time :)

Comment: @Albin Sure. Glad to hear. If you find my answer useful, please do accept it. `:)`